# Show Dialog Pop Up After if(confirm("¿text?")) validationEngine.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validation-engine

How can show a Dialog after the notification `if(confirm("... validationEngine.js`.
The dialog it is a `DIV`. this is the code of confirmation, the Dialog can show but the Dialog disappears automatically after submit.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#frm_datos_iniciales").validationEngine('attach',{
    onValidationComplete:function(form, status){
    if (status === true) { 
        if(confirm("¿Confirma la validez y el registro de los datos ingresados?")){
            $("#dialog").show().delay(5000).fadeOut(); //this is the call of Dialog
            form.validationEngine('detach');
            submit(); 

        }}}
    });
})
```

Comment: you need to prevent the form from posting right before validation confirms it

Comment: Yes, I agree but the Dialog appears behind of the alert confirmation